# How to apply grid system to contentplaceholder using Bootstrap?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting existing website into responsive website. As you can see in the image that there are 2 sides (leftcontent and rightcontent). I am new to Bootstrap. I tried using grid system.

[image]

How to apply grid system columns to contentplaceholder?

Code: (Master Page)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="leftcontent">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="sidecontentholder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </div>

<!--Start Main Content  -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="rightcontent">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="sidecontentholder" runat="server">
</asp:content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:content>
```

Comment: The contentplaceholders are inside a div with the classes `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9`. To apply further grid system you can add inside the page more div colums. Question is a little vague.. Check out [Grid examples](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp).

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan...hi sir...i wanted to make leftcontent and rightcontent responsive...i wanted to use row grid system but i am not getting how to use as there are two contentholders.

Comment: refer here [Bootstrap left & right align](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1202461/How-to-create-contentplaceholder-on-left-hand-side)